# What does concurrency_hint of boost::asio::io_service means?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-asio

From [`boost` doc](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/io_service/overload2.html):

> io_service(
>       std::size_t concurrency_hint);
>   Construct with a hint about the required level of concurrency.
>
> Parameters
>
> concurrency_hint A suggestion to the implementation on how many
>   threads it should allow to run simultaneously.

What does it mean 'A suggestion to the implementation'?

If I construct the object with '2', may it only start 1 thread?
If I have a CPU with 4 cores and I construct the object with '4', or '5' what will happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A concurrency hint allows the underlying implementation to make choices based on the amount of concurrent threads that should run the `io_service`.  For example:

- for I/O completion ports, it sets the maximum level of concurrency for the completion port.  The concurrency hint is provided as the `NumberOfConcurrentThreads` parameter to `CreateIoCompletionPort()`.  See the [I/O Completion Ports](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365198(v=vs.85).aspx#Threads_and_Concurrency) documentation for more details:

  > This value limits the number of runnable threads associated with the completion port. When the total number of runnable threads associated with the completion port reaches the concurrency value, the system blocks the execution of any subsequent threads associated with that completion port until the number of runnable threads drops below the concurrency value.
- when set to 1, the implementation is optimized to avoid unnecessary locking.  The [Revision History](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/boost_asio/history.html#boost_asio.history.asio_1_6_1___boost_1_48) notes:

  > Using thread-local operation queues in single-threaded use cases (i.e. when `concurrency_hint` is 1) to eliminate a lock/unlock pair.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, please let me know if I got it right: 
So the `concurrency_hint` says the size of the thread queue?
It doesn't relate to the real number of cores in the CPU, just saying: "you can run up to X concurrent threads in this `io_service`?

Comment: @hudac Yes.  For I/O completion ports, `concurrency_hint` sets the upper limit for the thread queue.  The cores will be a limit on thread parallelism, but thread concurrency can exceed the number of cores.  The linked I/O Completion Ports documentation provides recommendations for both the `NumberOfConcurrentThreads` value and thread pool size.

Comment: so why does it called `concurrency_hint` and not `concurrency`? Looks like the hint is the queue size itself, no?
Will your answer change for other thing than `I/O completion ports` ?
I mean, for any `boost::asio::io_service` which holds sockets, file descriptors, event fds, timer fds...

Comment: @hudac I think qualifying the parameter with _hint_ is appropriate.  Asio neither enforces nor guarantees the level of concurrency.  Currently, for the task based `io_service`, a `conccurency_hint` greater than 1 has no affect.  For I/O completion ports, under certain conditions, concurrency can exceed the the `NumberOfConcurrentThreads` value.

Comment: "Currently, for the task based io_service, a conccurency_hint greater than 1 has no affect" - This is the bottom line. Thank you very much.
I tried to run an example with `conccurency_hint` > 1 and it really do nothing special.
It's strange because I remember already doing it with success.. ;/

Comment: I found what I was looking for - in order to run more than 1 thread on `boost::asio::io_service`, more than 1 thread should `io_service.run()` it. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/threads.html